# How to send an MP3 file via email

Tags: email, mp3

I am Odeta Rose from USA. I want to send an mp3 file to my friend via email. I tried to send it but it’s showing me an error message that my email couldn't be sent. 
How can I send my file?
Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: *error message that my email couldn't be sent* Do not tell about the error, quote the whole message.

Comment: Try this service.....https://send.firefox.com/

Answer (score 1):

Most email services don't allow attachments of certain types or over a certain size.  You should check that the service you use allows files at least as large as the one you're trying to send and allows .mp3 files.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of the format, if you right click the file -> send to -> compressed zip folder then you should be able to send the compressed zip. They will need to extract this on the other side, but that is easily done. Just drag and drop or click extract.